# php scandir sort first single files then folders and subfolders

Tags: php, sorting, scandir

I have the following files and folders inside my '/templates' folder:

```
/templates/folder/contact.html
/templates/folder/index.html
/templates/folder/search.html
/templates/index.html
/templates/music.html
/templates/path/index.html
/templates/path/test.html
/templates/video.html
```

Now I want to get the list sorting first the single files,
and then the folders and subfolders, I mean:

```
/index.html
/music.html
/video.html
/folder/contact.html
/folder/index.html
/folder/search.html
/path/index.html
/path/test.html
```

And I am using this code, but I can't figure out how to sort them in that order.. Please help

```
<?php

function listFolderFiles($dir, $parent = ''){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    echo '<ol style="padding:0;">';
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
            echo '<li>'.$parent.'/'.$ff;
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)){
                listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff, $ff );
            }
            echo '</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ol>';
}

listFolderFiles('templates');

?>
```

**Please Note:** also actually this code outputs the subfolders one time as "empty", e.g. `/folder`
and the content inside the subfolders without the initial slash: `folder/contact.html`
but I need to have the initial slash like: `/folder/contact.html`
and remove the "empty" subfolders

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to have another alphabetical sorting there, you can go with storing directories (instead of recursive call) into an array and call `listFolderFiles` for all the elements in that array at the end of function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with your original recursive approach - without filename sorting (as outlined by @peter-vančo):

```
function listFolderFiles($dir, $parent = '')
{
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    $subfolders = array();

    echo '<ol style="padding:0;">';
    foreach($ffs as $ff)
    {
        if (!is_dir($dir . '/' . $ff))
        {
            echo '<li>'.$parent.'/'.$ff . '</li>';
        }
        else if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..')
        {
            $subfolders[$ff] = $dir.'/'.$ff;
        }
    }

    foreach($subfolders as $ff => $subfolderDir)
    {
        listFolderFiles($subfolderDir, '/' . $ff);
    }

    echo '</ol>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple Recursive iterator which one split Every items to: Folders and Files:

```
$MójFolder = __DIR__;
$Pliki = array('Pliki'=>array(), 'Foldery'=>array());
$Foldery = [];

$SkanerKatalogówIPlików = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($MójFolder, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$SkanujWszystkiePodkatalogi = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($SkanerKatalogówIPlików, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach($SkanujWszystkiePodkatalogi as $WszystkiePlikiIFoldery){
$Ścieżka = str_replace($MójFolder, '', $WszystkiePlikiIFoldery);

if($WszystkiePlikiIFoldery->isDir()){
    $Pliki['Foldery'][] = '.' . $Ścieżka .'/';
    natcasesort($Pliki['Foldery']);
}elseif($WszystkiePlikiIFoldery->isFile()){
    $Pliki['Pliki'][] = $Ścieżka ;
}
}
```